# Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio to move down multiple lines but keep the cursor in the same place?

Tags: visual-studio

CTRL+down arrow does this, but only 1 line at a time. Is there a shortcut to skip multiple lines but keep the cusor in the same place? You'd expect CTRL+page down to do it, but this just puts the cursor at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools + Options, Text Editor, pick your language or use All Languages, tick "Enable virtual space".  That ensures that the caret stays in the same column when you move it vertically, no matter what text is in a line.  Very much my personal preference.

Tools + Macros + Record is an easy way to generate the macro you want.  Tools + Customize + Keyboard to assign it a shortcut key.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a macro.  Well, except for that blasted tray icon.  I'm keeping the Windows taskbar on the left because of it.  The stupid balloon is killable.

Answer (score 2):

No. You could define your own macro though,and link it to a shortcut:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62.aspx